# How to view the .js file for a website that I did not create

Tags: javascript

When I am viewing websites that I don't own or create, is there a way to view the .js file?

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525

Answer (score 1):

If the code is not stored serverside, you could use chrome's developer tools, click on sources, and browse the .js file from there